# Трансформация Domain-сущностей в Presentation-сущности

Tags: android, архитектура

Если Presentation сущность отличается от Domain сущности, то на каком потоке её необходимо трансформировать в Presenter-е, если учесть, что в проекте используется RxJava.

Если трансформация занимает больше чем 16 ms, то может просесть фпс. И получается, что необходимо получать ответ от Interactor-а на Scheduler.IO, трансформировать данные и только потом, передавать данные на AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, всё верно.

Не стоит путать работу с потоками и то, в каком слое вы производите маппинг. Презентер имеет информацию и о бизнес моделях, и о моделях слоя презентации, соответственно он может конвертировать бизнес модельки в модельки презентации.

RxJava позволяет вам удобно перебрасывать задачи с одного потомка на другой. Соответственно, презентер получает `Observable` от интерактора в фоновом потоке (если у вас нет договорённости о том, что интерактор работает в фоновом потоке, вы можете добавить `SubscribeOn` в вызове из презентера) и использует специальный класс-маппер для преобразования бизнес модели. Затем, переключает поток на `Ui` и выполняет операции над вью.